# Movie library system

Tags: java, database, crud

I want to implement a crud movie library system and also some filtering capabilities.

Since it is so big, I have added the link to the code.

[https://github.com/neslihanbozer/Movie-Library](https://github.com/neslihanbozer/Movie-Library/tree/d3e8dbc700220ce290f8640cdb1f53fd15094da6).

I am aware it would be extendable in terms of testing. But what else could you suggest?

```
package com.movie.lib.service.impl;

import com.movie.lib.dto.MovieDto;
import com.movie.lib.entity.Movie;
import com.movie.lib.exception.MovieException;
import com.movie.lib.repository.MovieLibraryRepository;
import com.movie.lib.service.MovieLibraryCommandService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
@Transactional
public class MovieLibraryCommandServiceImpl implements MovieLibraryCommandService {

    private final MovieLibraryRepository movieLibraryRepository;

    public MovieLibraryCommandServiceImpl(MovieLibraryRepository movieLibraryRepository) {
        this.movieLibraryRepository = movieLibraryRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public String removeMovie(@Valid Long movieId) {

        try {

            Optional<Movie> movie = movieLibraryRepository.findById(movieId);

            if (movie == null || movie.get().getSoftDelete().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                throw new MovieException("Movie does not exist or already removed");
            } else {
                // Removes a movie via soft delete
                movie.get().setSoftDelete("1");
                movieLibraryRepository.save(movie.get());
            }

            return "Movie : " + movieId + " - Successfully removed";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new MovieException("Movie does not exist or already removed");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public String updateMovie(MovieDto movieDto) {

        try {

            var movie = movieLibraryRepository.findById(movieDto.getId());

            if (movie == null || movie.get().getSoftDelete().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                throw new MovieException("Movie does not exist");
            }

            Movie updatedMovie = Movie.builder()
                    .id(movie.get().getId())
                    .name(movieDto.getName())
                    .genre(movieDto.getGenre())
                    .actor(movieDto.getActor())
                    .duration(movieDto.getDuration())
                    .releaseYear(movieDto.getReleaseYear())
                    .status("1")
                    .softDelete("0")
                    .build();

            movieLibraryRepository.save(updatedMovie);

            return "Movie : " + movie.get().getId() + " - Successfully updated";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new MovieException("Exception while updating movie - " + e.getMessage());

        }
    }

    @Override
    public String addMovie(MovieDto movieDto) {

        try {
            Movie movie = Movie.builder()
                    .id(movieDto.getId())
                    .name(movieDto.getName())
                    .genre(movieDto.getGenre())
                    .actor(movieDto.getActor())
                    .status("1")
                    .duration(movieDto.getDuration())
                    .releaseYear(movieDto.getReleaseYear())
                    .softDelete("0")
                    .build();

            movieLibraryRepository.save(movie);

            return "Movie : " + movieDto.getId() + " - Successfully saved";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new MovieException("Exception while saving movie - " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please note that by our rules, external links can only be treated as supplementary material. If you want a review of more than this class, then that code has to be embedded directly in the question too.

Answer (score 1):

Now, I've really only looked at `MovieLibraryCommandServiceImpl` so far, and haven't looked at much of rest of the repo. Still, I have some comments on what I have seen:

I don't like how `status` and `softDelete` are numerical `String`s. Which statuses can exist? What do they mean? I feel like using `enum`s for those could communicate this in a clearer fashion

On the subject of `String`s, I find it kind of odd that these add/remove/update methods return a log message if, and only if, they succeed. First off, I wouldn't think formatting such messages is part of this class's purpose. Second, the situation where you're most likely to need a log message is when things have gone wrong, and in those situations you don't get a return value from those methods in the first place. Personally, I would change these  methods to be `void` - the caller already knows the ID of the movie they operate on (or they couldn't call these methods), and they know whether the operation succeeded (based on whether the methods return successfully or throw exceptions), so they're perfectly capable of formatting their own messages if they need to

I'm not a big fan of the way `Optional` is used here. Or, rather, the way `Optional` seemingly *isn't* used - half the point of `Optional` is to gain the ability to have objects do things based on whether or not they have a value (through `Optional::ifPresent`, `Optional::map`, `Optional::orElseGet`, etc). The other half is avoiding `null`. But this code takes advantage of none of that, only use `Optional::get` (which fails if the `Optional` is empty, suggesting that empty `Optional`s aren't being used). Additionally, there are methods which claim to return an `Optional<Movie>` but are treated as though they can return `null` - which is kind of redundant when `Optional.empty` exists. As much as I like `Optional`, it's only useful if it's actually *used*

Finally, the exception handling also raises some concerns to me

- First, `catch (Exception e)` is *very* broad, catching a wide variety of exceptions. This can sometimes be useful, but knowing exactly what you catch when and where is important, so you can respond appropriately. This code catches almost everything indicriminately, and handles it all the same way, which is usually not ideal. If you want, you *can* still commit to handling every failure state you can imagine, but right now you're *also* committing to handling every failure state you *can't* imagine, and that rarely ends well. Additionally, specifying which exception type(s) you're expecting where usually makes the code easier to understand
- Second, in those catch blocks, you create, and `throw`, a brand new exception, losing all information about the old one. So when something fails, all you get is a `MovieException` with little to no detail. That seems like a nightmare when debugging, as you'll have no idea what actually *caused* the failure. Personally, I'd suggest removing those `try`/`catch` blocks entirely, and just letting the original exception bubble up until someone can handle it properly. But if you *really* don't want that for some reason you should at least set the original exception as that new `MovieException`'s cause, so it can show up in stacktraces and such